# How do I use css in html

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I was learning html and css but when I got to this css code I was stuck. I couldn't make the paragraph text blue. Is there something wrong with my html?
This is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            p {color;blue;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This text is blue</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a semicolon `;` in your CSS between `color` and `blue`. It should be a colon `:`

Comment: Why the XHTML tag? The example is not XHTML.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong syntax of writing `color;blue;`

```
<style type="text/css">
    p {color:blue;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
p {
 color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong syntax of writing color;blue;
correct way::

```
<style type="text/css">
p {color:blue;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's right way. Instead semicolon you must write colon.

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            p {color: blue;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This text is blue </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Read more](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) about it.

Comment: @MrLister it is a feature of the Russian dialect. In Russia is accepted so to name it )

Answer (score 0):

example:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    p {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>This text is blue</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just simply - no style tag added

```
<p style="color:blue">This text is blue </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, so close. You've used a *semicolon* `;` instead of a *colon* `:`. Changing it would fix your issue.

```css
p { color: blue; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            p { color: blue; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This text is blue</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, if I may, I strongly suggest specifying a specific chain to your desired paragraphs. Making a global color change to all `p` tags isn't considered good practice.

```css
.paragraphs p {
    color: red;  
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraphs">
    <p>This text is red</p>
    <p>And so is this</p>
</div>

<p>This paragraph's color hasn't changed.</p>
```

On a side note. If desired, you could add a `style` attribute to your `p` tag to change the color of that specific paragraph.

```html
<p style="color: orange;">This text is orange</p>
<p>This paragraph's color hasn't changed.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy error to find, just distraction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        p {
          color:blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This text is blue</p>
</body>
</html>
```